# Meta-analysis with zeros for mean and sd

Tags: meta-analysis

When I do a meta-analysis with RevMan 5.3, mean and sd for group A is zero and zero, and mean and sd for group B is 47 and 2. The result is "not estimable". How to solve the problem?

Comment: it doesn't matter what software you are using, the result will be not estimable. The question then is why does RevMan think your mean and sd are zero?

Comment: This isn't really a software question, because the problem isn't w/ RevMan--any software will show this, as @JeremyMiles notes--the issue is statistical. This question is on topic here.

Comment: A SD or standard error should never be truly 0 (perhaps close or after rounding).

Comment: Can you show us the data which has an sd of zero?

Comment: The original data: Group A is 0. Group B is 48.0(42.0-49.9). Data are shown as median values and ranges are in parentheses. I convert group B "median and range" to "mean and SD" 47+/- 2. Group A is zero and zero.

Comment: The original data: Group A is 0. Group B is 48.0(42.0-49.9). Data are shown as median values and ranges are in parentheses. I convert group B "median and range" to "mean and SD" 47+/- 2. Group A is zero and zero.  Can I add 0.5 to Group A to make it estimable with group B in Revman? @Björn

Comment: Can I add 0.5 to Group A to make it estimable with group B in Revman? @JeremyMiles

Comment: The range of scores was zero? Everyone had the same score?

Comment: Median and range cannot be converted to mean and SD.

Comment: Yes. The original data of group A is zero. @JeremyMiles

Comment: I feel strange, too. @JeremyMiles

Comment: Is that range = min to max or = inter-quartile range (q1 to q3)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reason why you cannot include a dataset with mean and standard deviation of zero in your meta-analysis if you are using the mean difference or the standardised mean difference.
You do not  state your sample size so I have assumed it is 10 and using the R `metafor` package and its `escalc` function I get the following

`escalc(m1i = 0, sd1i = 0, n1i = 10, m2i = 47, sd2i = 2, n2i = 10, measure = "MD")
        yi     vi
1 -47.0000 0.4000
escalc(m1i = 0, sd1i = 0, n1i = 10, m2i = 47, sd2i = 2, n2i = 10, measure = "SMD")
        yi      vi
1 -31.8264 25.5231`

where $yi$ is the effect size and $vi$ its variance.

It is true that the formulae would not work if you had a sample size of zero as that would lead to a division by zero error.